# Nolan's Promises/A+ JavaScript puzzles

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have read [*We have a problem with promises*](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) by Nolan Lawson for a few times, but still have some questions about promises in JavaScript. At the end of Nolan's post you can find answers for four puzzles (I've attached screenshots here).

So, I have a few questions:

1. Why does `doSomethingElse()` function in the 1st puzzle have `undefined` value? To my mind, it must have `resultOfDoSomething` like in the 4th puzzle.
2. What's the difference between the 3rd and 4th puzzles? In the 3rd puzzle in the first `then` we write `doSomethingElse()` and in the 4th puzzle we write here only the name of function, `doSomethingElse`. How is it possible? What does really `doSomethingElse` do inside the `then` of the 4th puzzle?
3. Why does `doSomethingElse()` function in 3rd puzzle start at the same moment as `doSomething`?

[image: Puzzle 1 and 2]
[image: Puzzle 3 and 4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why does `doSomethingElse()` function in 1st puzzle [get passed] `undefined`?

Let us look at a simpler example:

```
foo();   // Line #1
foo(42); // Line #2
```

The difference between the two lines is what? On line #1, we are calling foo but passing it no value (hence `undefined`) whereas on line #2 we are calling foo and passing it 42.

Going back to the post:

```
doSomething().then(function () {
    return doSomethingElse( );
    //                     ^-- we are not passing a value
}).then(finalHandler);
```

How is this different to the 4th puzzle? In the 4th puzzle we are passing a reference to the function to `then`. Giving the promise the reference to the function allows it to call it at a later time with the result of the promise.<sup>[[1]](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-27)</sup>

---

> 2. What's the difference between the 3rd and 4th puzzles? In the 3rd puzzle [...] we write `doSomethingElse()` and in the 4th puzzle we write [...] `doSomethingElse`.

To explain the differences in the 3rd and 4th puzzles, let's look at simpler examples. How do the following two lines differ:

```
var foo = function foo() {
    return 42;
};
var a = foo;   // line #1
var b = foo(); // line #2
```

In the snippet above, `a` will contain a reference to the function `foo` whereas `b` will contain the result of calling foo (which would be 42).

---

> 3. Why does `doSomethingElse()` in the 3rd puzzle start at the same moment as `doSomething`?

Similar to the differences between the 3rd and 4th functions, note the use of `()` to **invoke** (or call) the function. Here we are calling both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` instead of waiting for the promise to "resolve" (waiting for the first call to finish). before Let us step through the execution:

1. Execute `doSomething` which returns a Promise
2. Attach the `doSomethingElse()` to the promise—but wait, `doSomethingElse()` is us calling `doSomethingElse()`, so that will happen async and we will attach the promise it returns to the promise `doSomething()` returned.
3. Attach the function `finalHandler` to the promise

Answer (score 2):

Long story short - simple 2 rules to make your examples understandable:

1. Returning a value from inside `.then` is the same as returning a promise that resolves with that value.
2. When you return nothing, it is the same as returning `undefined`, which in turn enacts rule #1.

If you keep these 2 in mind, your promise puzzles become clear as day.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> doSomething().then(function () {
>   return doSomethingElse();
> });
> ```
>
> Why does doSomethingElse() function in 1-st puzzle have undefined value? To my mind, it must have resultOfDoSomething like in 4-th puzzle.

The promised result of `doSomething` is passed to the anonymous function (which doesn’t even accept an argument). So whatever is passed there is lost. And `doSomethingElse` is called without any arguments, so the first function argument is `undefined`.

> ```
> doSomething().then(doSomethingElse());
>
> doSomething().then(doSomethingElse);
> ```
>
> What's the difference beetwen 3-rd and 4-th puzzles? In 3-rd puzzle in first then we write doSomethingElse() and in 4-th puzzle we write here only the name of function - doSomethingElse. How is it possible? What does really doSomethingElse do in then of 4-th puzzle?

Functions in JavaScript are objects which you can pass around as you like. That’s actually how the whole callback passing works: There is a function (here, it’s `then`) that takes a function as a parameter which is then later called.

So in the latter code, the function that is passed to `then` is `doSomethingElse` so that is the function which is *later* called. But in the former, we call `doSomethingElse` directly (with the parentheses `()`). So what gets passed to `then` is the *return value* of that function—which is unlikely a function that can be evaluated once the promise completes.

> Why does doSomethingElse() function in 3-rd puzzle start at the same moment as doSomething?

As I said, the function is immediately called, at the same time you call `doSomething`. Only the return value is passed to `then` which would then be called once the promise resolves.

Answer (score 1):

You must pay attention: `doSomethingElse` is a function reference while `doSomethingElse()` means that you "call" the function right away. Here you can get the result of the function, if any...

About promises I understood that:

A) The "then" method takes the result of the previous call and pass it as parameter to its own parameter if it is a function.

B) The execution is delayed only if the function  inside the "then" method returns something.

In these situations we have:

Puzzle 1) resultOfDoSomething is used as parameter for the anonymous function

```
function (){ return doSomethingElse ();}
```

This calls `doSomethingElse()` without parameters.

Puzzle 2)  the anonymous function does not return data so the next "then" is immediately executed

Puzzle 3) the expression `doSomethingElse()` is the result of the call of doSomethingElse. This value is used as parameter for the "then" method and since it is not a function (in this example!), we can pass to the other "then"...

finalHandler receives the last valid results as parameters, in this case resultOfDoSomething.

Puzzle 4) every "then" method receives as parameter the reference of a function. Each one of these functions will be called with the previous results as parameters. So, every function MUST wait for the result of the previous execution... and here you have the queue of the promises...

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `doSomethingElse()` function in the 1st puzzle have `undefined` value? To my mind, it must have `resultOfDoSomething` like in the 4th puzzle.

Nope. The `resultOfDoSomething` is passed to the callback that `then` was called with, yes, but we're simply ignoring it in the first code:

```
doSomething().then(function(resultOfDoSomething) {
//               it's here: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return doSomethingElse(  );
//          but not there: ^^ - Ooops!
});
```

> What's the difference between the 3rd and 4th puzzles? In the 3rd puzzle in the first then we write `doSomethingElse()` and in the 4th puzzle we write here only the name of function, `doSomethingElse`. How is it possible? What does really `doSomethingElse` do inside the then of the 4th puzzle?

As you probably know, it's the difference between a called function and the function itself.

Also, we always want - no: must - pass a callback function to `then(…)`. The following two are equivalent:

```
promise.then(function callback(res) {
    …
});
```

```
function callback(res) {
    …
}
promise.then(callback);
```

That's expected - you pass a function to the call, so it is chained onto the promise as usual. But `callback()` (with the invocation) is not a function any more:

> Why does `doSomethingElse()` function in 3rd puzzle start at the same moment as `doSomething`?

Because it is called immediately in the expression `then(doSomethingElse())` - it is in fact called before `then`, to which it is an argument. So it is in fact called a moment after `doSomething()`, but on the same event loop turn; and the two asynchronous somethings will run in parallel.

Also, `then` does only accept function arguments, everything else is *ignored*. So there is no chaining going on here, it's the same as doing

```
var promise = doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
promise.then(finalHandler);
```

Not what we want!

Btw, these are also explained as "*Advanced mistake #3: promises vs promise factories*" and "*Advanced mistake #5: promises fall through*", which I both would consider as rookie mistakes :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the execution order of is always first doSomethingElse then doSomethingElse and finalHandler. This is just JavaScript syntax.

Difference is that the args pass to function are different.

The two functions return two promises.The two promises execution order is show in figures you posted.  I think the author means the order of two promises not the function execution order.

```js
/**
 * Created by tshungle on 17-2-24.
 */
'use strict'
function doSomething() {
  console.log("doSomething start");
  sleep(1000)
  console.log("doSomething end");
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Promise of doSomething is about to resolve");
      resolve("doSomething resolvation")
    }, 2500);
  });

}

function doSomethingElse() {
  console.log("doSomethingElse start");
  sleep(1000);
  console.log("doSomethingElse end");
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Promise of doSomethingElse is about to resolve");
      resolve("doSomethingElse resolvation")
    }, 2500);
  });
}

function finalHandler(result) {
  console.log("finalHandler result is:", result);
}

function sleep(ms) {
  var stop = new Date().getTime();
  while(new Date().getTime() < stop + ms) {
    ;
  }
}


//1
 doSomething().then(function () {
   return doSomethingElse();
 }).then(finalHandler);

//2
// doSomething().then(function () {
//   doSomethingElse();
// }).then(finalHandler);
//
//3
// doSomething().then(doSomethingElse())
//   .then(finalHandler);

//4
// doSomething().then(doSomethingElse)
//   .then(finalHandler);
```